# Spresense SDK スタートガイドのHello WorldがMakeのエラーできない。

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDK　スタートガイドの順序に従ってHello worldをしようとしていました。
参考にしたのは以下のCLIとVSCodeによるHello Worldで環境はWindows 11です。
Versionは2.5.0です。

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html

CLIの3.1まではうまくいき、3.2のmakeで

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/name/spresense/nuttx/sched'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/msys64/home/name（名前が漢字なのでここは文字化けしている）/spresense/nuttx/include/nuttx/config.h', needed by 'clock_initialize.o'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/name/spresense/nuttx/sched'
make[1]: *** [tools/LibTargets.mk:59: sched/libsched.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/name/spresense/nuttx'
make: *** [Makefile:114: all] Error 2
```

というエラーが出ます。（ちなみにmake -jにするとターゲットは違うもののやはりNo rule to make targetが出ます）
どうしたらいいでしょうか？

上記がメインの質問ですが、参考のためVSCodeの方でも試した結果も書きます。
そちらでは、buildに至る前のコンフィグの部分で「コンフィグファイルの解析中にエラーが発生しました」と出てしまいます。stack overflowなどを参考に、SDKのフォルダでmake distcleanなどをしてみたものの結果は変わりません。
試しにそのままビルドしてみたところ、CLIと同じエラーが出ました。

Answer (score 1):

スペースや日本語を含むフォルダ名は禁止されているようです。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_制限事項](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90%E4%BA%8B%E9%A0%85)
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_制限事項](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90%E4%BA%8B%E9%A0%85)

別アカウントや別フォルダを作成して試してみるのが良いと思います。

Comment: これで動きました。ありがとうございました。